# How to make JavaFX TableView editable if rows are not bean-compliant?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

How to make cells editable in TableView in JavaFX?

I called `setEditable()`, called `setCellFactory()`, implemented `WrtitableValue` but this didn't help.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValueBase;
import javafx.beans.value.WritableObjectValue;
import javafx.beans.value.WritableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 * Table editing does not work
 */
public class TableViewEditable2 extends Application{

   public static class Person {
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;

      public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
      }
   }

   public static class FirstName extends ObservableValueBase<String> implements WritableValue<String> {

      private Person person;

      public FirstName(Person person) {
         this.person = person;
      }

      public String getValue() {
         return person.firstName;
      }

      public void setValue(String value) {
         person.firstName = value;
         fireValueChangedEvent();
      }
   }

   public static class LastName extends ObservableValueBase<String> implements WritableValue<String> {

      private Person person;

      public LastName(Person person) {
         this.person = person;
      }

      public String getValue() {
         return person.lastName;
      }

      public void setValue(String value) {
         person.lastName = value;
         fireValueChangedEvent();
      }
   }


   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

      ObservableList<Person> teamMembers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      teamMembers.add(new Person("John", "Johnson"));
      teamMembers.add(new Person("Ivan", "Ivanov"));

      TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
      table.setItems(teamMembers);
      table.setEditable(true);


      TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("First Name");
      firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
         public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> param) {
            FirstName ans = new FirstName(param.getValue());
            return ans;
         }
      });
      firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person>forTableColumn());



      TableColumn<Person,String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("Last Name");
      lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
         public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> param) {
            return new LastName(param.getValue());
         }
      });
      lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person>forTableColumn());



      table.getColumns().setAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);


      StackPane root = new StackPane();
      root.getChildren().add(table);

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

      primaryStage.setTitle("TableViewEditable2");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();



   }
}
```

Comment: That's an unusual setup, but doesn't it just work "out of the box" with a [`TextFieldTableCell`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html)?

Comment: Thanks. It started to call edit mode and allows editing, but forgetting new value upon end of edit.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me. I see the new values in the table, and adding some debug with `table.setOnMouseClicked(e -> { if (e.getClickCount()==2) { table.getItems().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.firstName + " " +p.lastName));}});` shows that the values are persisted to the object.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too :) So, didn't know now, when it started to to work :)